# str_replace or preg_replace only replacing last match?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace the final `</body>` tag on a page of HTML. There are many tags on the page (because of iFrames) so I need to replace only the last.

For example, if I had this code:

```
</body>
</body>
</body>
</body>
```

I need to replace the last `</body>` tag with something else.

I have tried to do `preg_replace("~(?!.*</body>)~",$replace_with,$content);` but it didn't work so well.

Any ideas?

Comment: would recommend to use HTML parsers to make your life easier

Comment: This seems easier if I can just get it right.

Answer (score 4):

We will exploit the greedy quantifier and use one advanced technique:

```
~.*\K</body>~s
```

Some explanation:

```
~        # A simple delimiter
.*       # Match anything greedy (until the end)
\K       # Forget what we matched until now
</body>  # Match ¨</body>¨
~        # The closing delimiter
s        # The s modifier to also match newlines with the dot ¨.¨
```

The PHP implementation could look like this:

```
$str = '
</body>
Something !
</body>
</body>
</body>
</body>
</html>';

$search = '</body>';
$replace = '</replaced>';

$str = preg_replace('~.*\K'. preg_quote($search, '~') . '~s', '$1' . $replace, $str);

echo $str;
```

Note that we used [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) to escape appropriate characters that might be used from untrusted users.

Output:

```
</body>
Something !
</body>
</body>
</body>
</replaced>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked for me! I had tried to use negative lookahead but had an error which killed my PHP script:  `$html = preg_replace('<\/body>(?!.*<\/body>)', '%%BODY_APPEND%%</body>', $html);`

Comment: @TrumanLeung I completely modified my answer since I think the old one was more of a hack. I would be confident to use this new solution in production. Take care :)